# Are questions of college admission and application submission allowed?

Tags: discussion, policy, scope

I am 31 year old and graduated with an Bachelors Degree nearly 10 years ago.  I'd like to go back to school for an entirely different field of expertise and earn a doctorate.

Are questions regarding such topics application for admissions allowed here on this site?  FYI, I did read the FAQ.  It seems a bit vague on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admissions to undergraduate programs are generally off-topic; admissions to graduate programs are on-topic, so long as they follow the group guidelines (in other words, be general enough that the answer might help someone else).

A question on "returning to school to pursue a doctorate in another field" would probably be on-topic. You could post a sample of your question here to check if it's OK.

Comment: Sir, I know this question is outside the site's focus: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41471/a-request-from-a-tenth-grader-for-advice-regarding-college-admissions 

But I really need advice. Where can I ask this question? Because it obviously can't be reworded to fit the rules, I have to give up hopes of getting it open here... I need to ask this elsewhere, but where? And I think I've asked a genuine enough question... So it's not that the question itself was improper... Any suggestions sir?